# He is the best of all , he thinks. -- Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> He is the best of all , he thinks.

Is the above sentence correct or the next one?

> "He is the best of all ", he thinks.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the first would be the most common usage. Such use of quotation marks would net be normal.

Another term is

> He thinks he hung the moon." meaning, is personally responsible for the moon.

Comment: Can you please explain the construction of the first sentence?